# How to set google firebase functions region in nuxt 3?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt 3 app and im deploying it via firebase and firebase functions, im using as per their docs to create a build:

```
NUXT_PRESET=firebase npm run build
```

and then to deploy

```
firebase deploy
```

This is all great and working fine but ive noticed that the firebase functions location is set to a US server when id like it to be europe, is there something i can add to either firebase.json or nuxt.config.js to change the server?

Previously in other applications ive had a functions folder within my application were you setup the firebase functions and that allowed me to set region but when using the NITO_PRESET which is great, it seems to handle all of that under the hood?

Comment: Do you have links to docs that could provide more insight into how to hook up Cloud Functions to Nuxt?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to continue to use type Cloud Function API calls, but not quite sure how to incorporate that into the build process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuxt 3.2.3 with Nitro 2.2.3

This works for me:

```
// nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  nitro: {
    preset: 'firebase',
    replace: {
      [`functions.https.onRequest`]: `functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest`,
    }
  },
})
```

And:

```json
// firebase.json

{
  // ...
  "hosting": {
    // ...
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "server",
        "region": "europe-west2"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: You superstar! works perfectly.

Comment: Sadly, I'm getting `Error: Unable to find a valid endpoint for function. Functions matching the rewrite are present but in the wrong region.` after adding `"region": "europe-west1",` to the `firebase.json`.